# Why are the prediction error estimate and the true prediction error negatively correlated?

Tags: r, estimation, cross-validation, prediction

Section 12.2 of [Computer Age Statistical Inference](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/CASI_files/PDF/casi.pdf) reports simulation results that indicate that the cross-validated estimate of the prediction error for a given prediction rule is negatively correlated to the true prediction error.

In the discussion, the authors relate this finding to cross-validation estimating the prediction error on a *random training set*, as well as on a random response to be predicted, making cross-validation a "*strongly frequentist device*". How is this observation related to the negative correlation between the two objects? Is there a more concrete explanation, e.g. in a toy model?

I attach some R Code that replicates Figure 12.3 and Table 12.3 in the text.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(glmnet)
library(glmnetUtils)
# load data:
supernova <- as.tibble(data.table::fread("https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/CASI_files/DATA/supernova.txt", sep = " ", header = F, drop = 1, col.names = c("E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "E8", "E9", "E10", "Magnitude")))
# function to compute true error and cross-validated error:
getErrors <- function(supernova){
  # sample data:
  supernova.star <- supernova %>% sample_n(39, replace = T)
  # cross validate:
  cv.out <- cv.glmnet(Magnitude ~ ., data = supernova.star)
  mod <- glmnet(Magnitude ~ ., data = supernova.star, lambda = cv.out$lambda.min)
  # error estimates:
  err.cv <- cv.out$cvm[which(cv.out$lambda == cv.out$lambda.min)]
  err.app <- mean((supernova.star$Magnitude - predict(mod, newdata = supernova.star)) ^ 2)
  err.true <- mean((supernova$Magnitude - predict(mod, newdata = supernova)) ^ 2)
  return(c(err.true, err.cv, err.app))
}
# run simulations:
set.seed(42)
err <- matrix(nrow = 500, ncol = 3)
colnames(err) <- c("True", "CV", "Apparent")
for(i in 1 : 500){
  err[i, ] <- getErrors(supernova)
}
err <- as.tibble(err)
# Figure 12.3
plot(err$True, err$CV, ylab = "True", xlab = "Estimated")
abline(lm(CV ~ True, data = err), col = "red")
# Table 12.3
rbind(sapply(err, mean), sapply(err, sd))
# Correlation matrix:
cor(err)
```

**EDIT: I added the plot of estimated prediction error (x-axis) vs. true prediction error (y-axis)**

[image: Estimated prediction error (x-axis) vs. true prediction error (y-axis), regression line (red)]

Comment: Could you include the plots that are produced by this code?